# Why isn't my Ajax contact form getting emails?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, contact-form

I'm trying to set up a contact form  but but it's not working for some reason and I'm not sure why.

Here is contactform, my ajaxform.js and the parser_callback function in my functions.php.

**contact-form**

```
<div id="form-response">
</div>
<form class="contact-form" method="post" action="" id="ajaxContactForm">
<div class="upper-form">
<div class="contact-input"><input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Your name" required></div>
<div class="contact-input"><input type="email" id="mail" placeholder="Your mail" required></div>
</div>
<div class="contact-input"><textarea id="message" placeholder="Your message" rows="10" required></textarea></div>
<div class="lower-form">
<div class="contact-input"><span class="status"></span></div>
<div class="contact-input"><input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Send"></div>
</div>
</form>
```

**ajaxform.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
console.log( "ready!" );
    $( '#ajaxContactForm' ).submit(ajaxSubmit);

function ajaxSubmit(e){

e.preventDefault();
var name = $( "#name" ).val();
var mail = $( "#mail" ).val();
var message = $( "#message" ).val();
var replyText = $( "#form-response" );
var status = $( ".status" );

$( "#submitButton" ).attr("disabled", true);
status.html( 'please wait...' );
console.log(status);
function clearForm() {
    $( "#name" ).val( '' ); 
    $( "#mail" ).val( '' );
    $( "#message" ).val( '' );
}

    $.ajax({ //ajax request
         url: MyAjax.ajaxurl, //wp's own admin-ajax.php that will handle the request
         type: 'POST', //what kind of request: its a post-request, we are sending data to the server
         datatype: 'json', //what datatype received back, explicitly stated json wanted
         data: { //actual data sending
            "action": 'parser_callback', //what action to execute, in this case parser_callback in functions.php
            name: name,
            mail: mail,
            message: message,
            "nonce": MyAjax.nonce //send the nonce for security
         },
         success: function( response ) {
             status.html( response );
             replyText.html ( '<h2>Thanks for contacting me '+ name +'! I will get back to you as soon as possible.</h2>' );
             clearForm();
             $( "#submitButton" ).attr("disabled", false);
         },
         error: function( error ) {
             status.html( response );
             $( "#submitButton" ).attr("disabled", false);
         },
         beforeSubmit : function(arr, $form, options){
            arr.push( { "name" : "nonce", "value" : MyAjax } );
         }
    });
    return false;
    }
    });
```

**parser_callback (in functions.php)**

```
function parser_callback() {

        wp_send_json_error( 'You suck!' ); // to see if the ajax request to parser is successfully sent.

        if ( ! check_ajax_referer( 'ajax-contact-nonce', 'nonce' ) ) { // to see if nonce checks out
            return wp_send_json_error( 'Invalid nonce' );
        }

    if ( isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['mail']) && isset($_POST['message']) ) { 
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $mail = $_POST['mail'];
        $message = nl2br($_POST['message']);
        $to = "<mail@mymail.se>";
        $from = "<$mail>";
        $subject = 'Contactform from mysite.com sent';
        $message = '<b>Name:</b> '.$name.' <br><b>Email:</b> '.$mail.' <p>'.$message.'</p>';
        $headers = "From: $from" . "\r\n" . "Reply-to: $mail" . "\r\n" . "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
        $headers .= "MIME-version: 1.0\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n"; //Fixes ÅÄÖ in Sender name and Message


        if( mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=', $message, $headers) ) { //Fixes ÅÄÖ in subject 
            echo "success"; 

        } else { 
            echo "The server failed to send the message. Please try again later."; 
        } 
    } 
    exit();
    }
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_parser', 'parser_callback' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_parser', 'parser_callback' );
```

When I test my form I get no errors (I have error report-handling added in functions.php) except the "You suck!" json_error in network log which indicates that the ajax request to the parser-function is not successfully, I dont know why though.

Also, the "Thanks for contacting me.."-text is displayed but there is no echoes of Success or Server failed. I don't get any other info using the inspect and/or console from chrome tools either.

Comment: AJAX has no bearing on whether e-mail gets sent or not. The only question re: AJAX is to check the data is being sent to the server as you think it is. Check this via the network log in the browser, or run `print_r($_REQUEST)` on the server-side script to check you're receiving what you should be. If you are, you can remove AJAX from the conundrum.

Comment: The wp_send_json_error( 'You suck!' ); message is in the network showing. So the ajax request to the parser-function is not sent properly. Why is that?

Comment: The AJAX request _is_ being sent to your function, otherwise you wouldn't be seeing the `You suck!` message. Have you read what the [wp_send_json_error()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_send_json_error) function does?

Comment: The fact that the request complete does *not* mean that the information you think you're passing to it is getting sent. This is a basic debugging step. Run `print_r($_REQUEST)` and check, before anything else, that the variables are coming through.

Comment: When I run it in the top of the function it says: Array ( [action] => parser [name] => Random Name [mail] => amail@gmail.com [message] => Amessage [nonce] => bf2a9a93c3 ) int(2) string(164) "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by AND array(2) { ["success"]=> bool(false) ["data"]=> string(9) "You suck!" } ["status_code"]=> NULL } {"success":false,"data":"You suck!"}

So name, mail and message are sent but not replytext or status - is this why its not working?

Comment: I also wonder about the "action"-value in the JS. Should it be exactly the name of the php function or not? And in the contact-form should action have a value?